# How to configure an old touchscreen with one-finger gestures?

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen

I have an old T100TA tablet and I'd like to use the touch screen with it. If I do xinput list, it shows up in the device list as "ATML1000:00 03EB:8C0E". It looks like it is configured for multi touch, because when I pull stuff with one finger it starts to drag files and select text in the browser. So I guess scrolling would go with two fingers. As far as I can tell this touch screen does not support multi touch, so what I need is some basic setup for one finger gestures e.g. scrolling for one tap and drag, moving stuff with two tap and drag, but xinput does not seem to allow such configuration. For example I tried to set the "ScrollMethod" to "edge", but I got the message that it is not a defined property for the touch screen. I installed the synaptics driver and tried with that too, but it does not show up in the input device list with that driver and in the logs I found it tries to do multi touch with that too. I have the same experience with the touch pad too, which shows up as "Asus TouchPad", but there I was able to set at least edge scrolling. Is there any solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: First detail require is knowing your software stack, ie. what OS/product/release are you asking about?

Comment: I investigated a little bit, in 2014 the screen had multitouch support, in 2016 no longer had it, so the problem is the current driver and I don't start to write a driver or try to hack the old one into the kernel. I don't do low abstraction level programming. http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/ http://www.jfwhome.com/2016/01/04/latest-steps-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-asus-t100ta/ It won't work with Ubuntu no matter what I do.